# R nsltools Regression, preview function doesn't take variables

Tags: r, variables, regression, nls

im quite new to R but wanted to use the packages "nls" and "nlstools" since it has nice tools for analysis and evaluation.

the code I use is:

```
conB1_2015 = read.csv("C:\\Path_to_File\\conB1_2015.csv")
conB1_2015 = na.omit(conB1_2015)
tRef <- mean(conB1_2015$Mean_Soil_Temp_V2..C., na.rm=TRUE)
rRef <- conB1_2015$Lin_Flux..mymol.m.2.s.1.[which.min(abs(conB1_2015$Mean_Soil_Temp_V2..C.-tRef))]
rMax <- max(conB1_2015$Lin_Flux..mymol.m.2.s.1., na.rm=TRUE)
half <- rMax/2
half_SM <- conB1_2015$Soil_Moist_V3[which.min(abs(conB1_2015$Lin_Flux..mymol.m.2.s.1.-half))]
form <- as.formula(Lin_Flux..mymol.m.2.s.1. ~ (rRef)*a*exp(b*Mean_Soil_Temp_V2..C.)*Soil_Moist_V3/(half_SM)+Soil_Moist_V3)
preview(form, data = conB1_2015, start = c(a = -1.98, b = -0.05), variable = 1)
```

The Problem is, that i get this Error running this code:
Error in data.frame(value, row.names = rn, check.names = FALSE) : 
  row names supplied are of the wrong length
When i change the variables in `form <- as.formula(Lin_Flux..mymol.m.2.s.1. ~ (rRef)*a*exp(b*Mean_Soil_Temp_V2..C.)*Soil_Moist_V3/(half_SM)+Soil_Moist_V3)`

to `form <- as.formula(Lin_Flux..mymol.m.2.s.1.~(rRef<-4.41)*a*exp(b*Mean_Soil_Temp_V2..C.)*Soil_Moist_V3/(half_SM<-7.19)+Soil_Moist_V3)`

the function works fine.
I wanted to automate the script to run over several csv's to test different models on different data. Is it really not possible to pass variables into the preview function or am I missing something? There can't be a problem with headers or the data table since it's working fine in the second example.